# cannot delete files from exFAT drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, unicode, exfat

I copied a few files and folders with unicode characters from my FAT32 drive to the exFAT drive... now I see the files and folders but cannot delete or examine them (file not found).

So exFAT does not support unicode (čšž...) in file names?

I tried to see the short name with dir /x but on Win7 this switch seems to have no effect...

Please help! I think I'll *probably* be able to live without unicode in file names but I'd really like to delete those files now...

thank you!
david

Answer (score 2):

## exFAT:

> **Supported:**
>
> > `UTF-16` [Character Support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm)
>
> **Unsupported:**
>
> > `U+0000` (*NUL*) through `U+001F` (*US*)
> >
> >  / (*Slash*)
> >
> >  \ (*Backslash*)
> >
> >  : (*Colon*)
> >
> >  * (*Asterisk*)
> >
> >  ? (*Question Mark*)
> >
> >  " (*Double Quote*)
> >
> >  < (*Less Than*)
> >
> >  > (*Greater Than*)
> >
> >  | (*Pipe*)

You can use `iconv` from [GNUWin32](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm), it works the same as the GNU/Linux counterpart:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 filename.txt
```

you can then use it with batch, provided you've added it to your `%PATH%`:

```
for /f %x in ('dir /b *.txt') do iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 %x
```

Comment: hmm so you're saying that it should support unicode? why do I have problems then? iconv is for converting unsupported chars to supported? also don't understand.. sorry and thanx!

Comment: I tried to copy another file, this time with "ü" character and this worked?! ččcžž.txt did not work... so those characters cause problems and I cannot delete the file... and I want those letters in files I just decided (I cannot live without that).. so I want it to work completely... can someone try to copy the file named "ččcžž.txt" to an exFAT external HDD please? thank you

Comment: Man, this filesystem is the worst.

Answer (score 0):

I formatted the drive again from Windows and there was the same problem... and I also read that exFAT is not journaled... so it looks like it's not that good and it seems unreliable.. I will use NTFS and install Paragon NTFS driver on my Mac to be able to write from it.